# Node Fastify - serve images located in upload folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Make **files/images** available to be access, when we navigate to

`localhost:8000/properties/files/[image name]`

`localhost:8000/properties/files/1635843023660-profile.jpg`

**File Structure**

```
node_modules
src/
uploads/
    1635843023660-profile.jpg
    1635843023668-home.jpg
...
.env
package.json
```

**index.js**

```
import Fastify from "fastify";
import FastifyStatic from "fastify-static";
import path from "path";
import { propertiesRoutes } from "./routes/properties.js";
...
export const fastify = await Fastify({ logger: process.env.LOGGER || true });

const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));
fastify.register(FastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "uploads"),
});
fastify.register(propertiesRoutes, { prefix: "/properties" });
...
```

**routes/properties.js**

```
export const propertiesRoutes = function (fastify, opts, done) {
  ...
  fastify.get("/images/:name", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/uploads/" + req.params.name);
  });
  done();
};
```

as of right now I'm getting

> {"message":"Route GET:/properties/images/1635843023660-profile.jpg not
> found","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When not specifiying a `prefix` in your `FastifyStatic` config, the default `/` will be used. So in order to access your static files you need to change your request path from `/properties/images/<your-img.jpg>` to `/images/<your-img.jpg>`.

Alternatively you could use a custom prefix like `public` like they did in the [documentation](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static#usage):

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'),
  prefix: '/public/',
})
```

and then request it with `/public/images/<your-img.jpg>`.